# executeFetchRequest - Error: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: swift, core-data, unrecognized-selector

I am a C# software developer so I have knowledge how to do programming on Windows, but I am a complete newbie on OS X, XCode and Swift.

I write a code that uses Core Data entity called "SharesEntity" and I try to use NSExpression to determine the maximum value of an attribute, called "sorrend" (order). But when I execute the code I get an error:

"unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x127"

The error occures here : **try orderResults = context!.executeFetchRequest(orderRequest)**

```
var appDel : AppDelegate?
var context : NSManagedObjectContext?
var iOrder : Int32 = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    appDel = (NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
    context = appDel!.managedObjectContext
    betoltes()
}

func sorrend() {

    let orderRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "SharesEntity")
    orderRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.DictionaryResultType

    let keyPathExpression = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "sorrend")
    let maxExpression = NSExpression(forFunction: "max:", arguments: [keyPathExpression])

    let expressionDescription = NSExpressionDescription()
    expressionDescription.name = "maxSorrend"
    expressionDescription.expression = maxExpression
    expressionDescription.expressionResultType = NSAttributeType.Integer32AttributeType

    var expressionDescriptions = [AnyObject]()
    expressionDescriptions.append(expressionDescription)
    orderRequest.propertiesToFetch = expressionDescriptions

    var orderResults:NSArray?
    do {
       try orderResults = context!.executeFetchRequest(orderRequest)
     } catch {
       print("Oops! Error occured.")
     }

     if (orderResults!.count > 0) {
        iOrder = orderResults![0].valueForKey("maxSorrend") as! Int32
     }

     print("Sorrend: ", iOrder)
}
```

Error Stack:

```
Printing description of orderRequest:
<NSFetchRequest: 0x6100000cce10> (entity: SharesEntity; predicate: ((null)); sortDescriptors: ((null)); type: NSDictionaryResultType; includesPendingChanges: NO; propertiesToFetch: ((
"(<NSExpressionDescription: 0x610000163a80>), name maxSorrend, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity (null), renamingIdentifier maxSorrend, validation predicates (\n), warnings (\n), versionHashModifier (null)\n userInfo {\n}"
)); )
2016-04-23 17:30:33.436 iShares[2448:156683] -[__NSCFNumber count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x127
2016-04-23 17:30:33.437 iShares[2448:156683] -[__NSCFNumber count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x127
2016-04-23 17:30:33.440 iShares[2448:156683] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82e284f2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff97b22f7e objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82e921ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82d98571 ___forwarding___ + 1009
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff82d980f8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   Foundation                          0x00007fff899f8579 +[_NSPredicateUtilities max:] + 56
6   Foundation                          0x00007fff8981c5fb -[NSFunctionExpression expressionValueWithObject:context:] + 1094
7   CoreData                            0x00007fff90648f8a -[NSMappedObjectStore executeFetchRequest:withContext:] + 2122
8   CoreData                            0x00007fff906a3288 __65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 4120
9   CoreData                            0x00007fff906adb63 gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform + 179
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001005cdcc5 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001005cf3db _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 375
12  CoreData                            0x00007fff9069c662 _perform + 194
13  CoreData                            0x00007fff905e05c5 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 533
14  CoreData                            0x00007fff905ded4a -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 586
15  iShares                             0x00000001000040a7 _TFC7iShares14ViewController7sorrendfT_T_ + 1047
16  iShares                             0x0000000100002ee0 _TFC7iShares14ViewController9hozzaadasfPs9AnyObject_T_ + 64
17  iShares                             0x0000000100003c76 _TToFC7iShares14ViewController9hozzaadasfPs9AnyObject_T_ + 54
18  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff92e1707a _os_activity_initiate + 75
19  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c7fce89 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 460
20  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c80efde -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86
21  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c80ef08 __26-[NSCell _sendActionFrom:]_block_invoke + 131
22  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff92e1707a _os_activity_initiate + 75
23  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c80ee65 -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 144
24  libsystem_trace.dylib               0x00007fff92e1707a _os_activity_initiate + 75
25  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c80d48a -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 2693
26  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c855fd0 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 744
27  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c80bbb4 -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 669
28  AppKit                              0x00007fff8cd60469 -[NSWindow _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 6322
29  AppKit                              0x00007fff8cd6144d -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 212
30  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c7a063d -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 517
31  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c720b3c -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 2540
32  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c587ef6 -[NSApplication run] + 796
33  AppKit                              0x00007fff8c55146c NSApplicationMain + 1176
34  iShares                             0x000000010000b264 main + 84
35  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff921315ad start + 1
36  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
```

Breakpoint result for +[_NSPredicateUtilities max:]:

```
Foundation`+[_NSPredicateUtilities max:]:
0x7fff899f8541 <+0>:    pushq  %rbp                      ; this line was highlighted

0x7fff899f8542 <+1>:    movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x7fff899f8545 <+4>:    pushq  %r15
0x7fff899f8547 <+6>:    pushq  %r14
0x7fff899f8549 <+8>:    pushq  %r13
0x7fff899f854b <+10>:   pushq  %r12
0x7fff899f854d <+12>:   pushq  %rbx
0x7fff899f854e <+13>:   subq   $0x258, %rsp              ; imm = 0x258 
0x7fff899f8555 <+20>:   movq   %rdx, %r14
0x7fff899f8558 <+23>:   movq   %rdi, %rbx
0x7fff899f855b <+26>:   movq   -0x163ec1da(%rip), %rax   ; (void *)0x00007fff735cc070: __stack_chk_guard
0x7fff899f8562 <+33>:   movq   (%rax), %rax
0x7fff899f8565 <+36>:   movq   %rax, -0x30(%rbp)
0x7fff899f8569 <+40>:   movq   -0x163336d0(%rip), %rsi   ; "count"
0x7fff899f8570 <+47>:   movq   %r14, %rdi
0x7fff899f8573 <+50>:   callq  *-0x163ebbf9(%rip)        ; (void *)0x00007fff97b134c0: objc_msgSend
0x7fff899f8579 <+56>:   testq  %rax, %rax
0x7fff899f857c <+59>:   je     0x7fff899f8947            ; <+1030>
0x7fff899f8582 <+65>:   movq   -0x1632cf79(%rip), %rsi   ; "_getCommonTypeFor:"
0x7fff899f8589 <+72>:   movq   -0x163ebc10(%rip), %r15   ; (void *)0x00007fff97b134c0: objc_msgSend
...
```

I use Google daily basis but couldn't find the solution so far. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Update your question with the complete error message and point out the line causing the error.

Comment: What is `context`?  Because the address `0x127` makes it look like something is probably `NULL`, and Swift's type checking didn't catch it somehow (or you're building with `-Ofast`).

Comment: context is initialized in func viewDidLoad. (I just updated the post to indicate that piece of code as well).

Comment: This looks like it's going to be really hard to debug.  First, can you set an exception breakpoint?  Then, when the breakpoint hits, go to `+[_NSPredicateUtilities max:]` in the debugger.  It will show you a bunch of assembly code.  Can you post that code & which line of it is highlighted?

Comment: It did not return with `+[_NSPredicateUtilities max:]` but with `-[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:]` it show a thousand line assembly code. I won't copy it here. It stopped on this line (if it says anything) `0x7fff905ded4a <+586>:  xorl   %r12d, %r12d`

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not return?"  Is `+[_NSPredicateUtilities max:]` even in the stack trace this time?  Also, you don't need to paste the entire assembly code; just 10 lines or so around the highlighted line.

Comment: No it's not in the stack. But as I figured out the problem may occure before. I went through the stack trace and the error (unrecognized selector sent to instance) appeares twice. Exception breakpoint stops at the the first, but there is no stack trace presents at this point yet.

Comment: Is 0x127 one of the values of sorrend?

Comment: @Willeke The app is crashing because the selector `length` is being sent to 0x127, which is too low of a memory address to be an object.  The system is interpreting it as a tagged pointer, which it possibly is supposed to be, but it could just be an offset added to a NULL pointer.

Comment: I would like to start with `+[_NSPredicateUtilites max:]` so then we can work our way back up the stack to find out where the `0x127` is coming from.  What if you set a breakpoint on `+[_NSPredicateUtilites max:]` itself?

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot set up an exception breakpoint on `+[_NSPredicateUtilites max:]`. I don't know how to do that. As I mentioned before when the exception breakpoint stops the running of code, it stops on `-[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:]`

Comment: Go to the Breakpoint navigator, and click Add Symbolic Breakpoint instead of Add Exception breakpoint, and enter `+[_NSPredicateUtilities max:]`.  I have to go right now, but I'll check back occasionally.

Comment: Ok, I updated the post with the new debug results. Thanks for your help @NobodyNada.

Comment: @Balazs This might be avoiding the problem, rather than fixing it, but an alternative approach to get the maximum value of `sorrend` is to use a fetch sorted by `sorrend` (descending) and a `fetchLimit` of 1.

Comment: @pbasdf Yes, I thought about it. But in C# world it wouldn't be an elegant solution. I assume it is not an elegant solution in Swift world either. :) So I would keep this solution as the last possibility.

Comment: @Balazs In Core Data that **IS** an elegant solution. You are letting the persistent store do the work in a way that it is intended to.

Comment: Can you post some assembly from `-[NSFunctionExpression expressionValueWithObject:context:]` (by breaking on `+[_NSPredicateUtilities max:]` and backtracking up the stack)?